# PHP Post with Header and XML Content

Tags: php, post, youtube, header, gdata

I want to subscribe a YouTube Channel through the GData API via PHP.

[image: Documentation]

How can i do this post in PHP?

I tried it like this but the page keeps loading forever:

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'gdata.php' // For $DEVKEY

function post_xml($url, $xml) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array(
  "Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
  "Content-Length: 1024",
  "Authorization: Bearer $token",
  "GData-Version: 2",
  "X-GData-Key: key=$DEVKEY"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $xml );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}    

$token = $_SESSION['token'];

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/subscriptiontypes.cat"
      term="channel"/>
    <yt:username>GoogleDevelopers</yt:username>
</entry>';

$url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/subscriptions';

echo post_xml($url, $xml);

?>
```

In HttpRequester i already managed it to do a HTTP Post Request and it worked. I think the problem is the content of the Request. How do i properly give the text which is in "Content" (look at the screenshot) via PHP (cURL)?

[image: HttpRequester]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `$xml` as POSTFIELDS and it should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
```

And add the correct content-length:

```
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml),
```

When you're planning to do more, like PUT-requests with data and just lots of REST-requests, I would suggest to use some kind of package like [Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com). Curl has it's pitfalls...

Comment: It keeps loading forever :/

Comment: Too bad, I was having trouble with the same thing (different API though, but with POST and XML data) and this fixed it for me. Is the API call supposed to return any content? Because you ask for any response body (`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER `) and I can imagine there would only be a HTTP 200 response.

Comment: Oh, i think PHP still tried to do the all posts, because my whole apache server was slow. I restarted and it works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code below, hope it will help

```
 $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
        "Connection: close",
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($res);
```